# Norm of $Ax$ creates norm of $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose that 
$A = \pmatrix{3&4\\5&6}.$ Is the $2$-norm of $Ax$ a norm for $x$?

Comment: Presumably you know the requirements of a norm. What's stopping you from just checking?

Comment: I can't seem t prove the sub additive property

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the function $n(x) = \|Ax\|$ is a norm. As always, you can prove that $n$ is a norm by checking that it satisfies the subadditive, absolute homogeneity, and point-separating properties ([all defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition)).  The fact that $n$ is point-separating requires that you notice a particular property of the matrix $A$ that your are given.

To show that $n$ is subadditive, note that for vectors $x,y$ we have
$$
n(x+y) = \|A(x+y)\| = \|Ax + Ay\| \leq \|Ax\| + \|Ay\| = n(x) + n(y).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because given a $(n\times m)$ matrix $A$ and a norm on $\Bbb R^n$, the function $\lVert Ax\rVert$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^m$ if and only if $\ker A=\{0\}$